# gfortran cannot open file No such file or directory

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to call files in Fortran code through a shell script in my ubuntu (installed in virtual box).
But Fortran is unable to find the file. Following is my shell script and Fortran code. I wrote a simple Fortran code to test.

Shell Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

path=/media/sf_D_DRIVE/1_work/jpl/1_NPP/aerosol_ccn_arm/101_temporal_avg
in1=$path/ccn/CCN_fixed_ss_5min.txt

echo $in1 > infile
./test.out < infile
```

Fortran Code:

```
    Character*180::in1f,in2f
    integer::ny,nm,nd,nh,nmi,ns,cy,cm,cd,ch,cmi,cs
    real::cn,ccn,ss

    read*,in1f
    open(11,file=in1f,status='old')
5   read(11,*,end=90)cy,cm,cd,ch,cmi,cs,ccn,ss
         print*,cy,cm,cd,ch,cmi,cs,ccn,ss
    go to 5
90  stop
    end
```

Error:

```
At line 6 of file test.f90 (unit = 11)
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file '': No such file or directory

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f8f52ea3d0a
#1  0x7f8f52ea4819
#2  0x7f8f52ea54ef
#3  0x7f8f530e18b6
#4  0x7f8f530e1bac
#5  0x561f0de0e2e2
#6  0x561f0de0e589
#7  0x7f8f52cb90b2
#8  0x561f0de0e13d
#9  0xffffffffffffffff
```

I am unable to find the error in the code.

Comment: To read a filename containing a `/` it will be necessary to use an `A` edit descriptor, as shown (and for the reasons given) in the linked question and answers.  Something like `read '(A180)', in1f`.

Comment: Thank you @francescalus. This works perfectly for me.